# Ruby comparing two identical strings returns false

Tags: ruby

```
> [x[1].txt,x[0].txt]
[
    [0] "Put your weight on to the shoulders and upper back.",
    [1] "Put your weight on to the shoulders and upper back."
]
> [x[1].txt,x[0].txt].map &:class
[
    [0] String < Object,
    [1] String < Object
]
> x[1].txt == x[0].txt
false
```

How can that be possible?

**UPDATE**

After reading a bit i found out this:

```
y = x.map{|z| z.txt.toutf8 }
[
    [0] "Put your weight on to the shoulders and upper back.",
    [1] "窶ィPut your weight on to the shoulders and upper back.",
    [2] "窶ィPut your weight on to the shoulders and upper back."
]
```

So the strings are not the same, but without .toutf8 it looks exactly the same, what is the reason?

and most important, how can I strip those chars?

Comment: There must be something else going on here. What is `x`?

Comment: x is an activerecord model..

Comment: What's the result of `x.collect { |_x| _x.txt }.uniq` equal?

Comment: What is the result of `x[1].txt.codepoints` / `x[0].txt.codepoints` and what does `x1.txt.method(:==)` return?

Comment: check my update please

Comment: My answer is updated to reflect your update.

Answer (score 1):

The strings may be different encodings.  To find out the encoding for the strings, try this:

```
[x[1].txt.encoding,x[0].txt.encoding]
```

If it turns out to be the case, it could be an issue from an interface (e.g. a View, a REST API endpoint, or a file source), or it could be a storage/translation issue with the database.

If your string encodings are mismatched, you can do the following:

```
x.map {|text| text.encode!("UTF-8", invalid: :replace, undef: :replace).force_encoding("utf-8") }
```

If your encodings are already matched, you can strip those non-ASCII characters from the strings with this `gsub` call:

```
x.map {|text| text.gsub!(/[^\001-\176]+/, "") }
```

Once you've done this, you get the following:

```
[
  [0] "Put your weight on to the shoulders and upper back.", 
  [1] "Put your weight on to the shoulders and upper back.", 
  [2] "Put your weight on to the shoulders and upper back."
]
```

The regex will remove any characters that are between ASCII code 1 (octal 001) and ASCII code 126 (octal 176).  This effectively scrubs the string of any non-ASCII characters (and ASCII 0).

If you require "extended ASCII" for use with an international character set, such as ISO-8859 character set or Windows 1252, or even specific Unicode characters, you can extend the range to include those characters by changing the digits to include those characters.

Comment: It returns `NoMethodError: undefined method `encoding' for "Put your weight on to the shoulders and upper back.":String` its ruby 1.8.7